# Which Ubuntu version works best for my system (see below)?

Tags: boot

my configuration:
Sony Vaio laptop, Windows 7 Starter service pack 1, 32-bit; 1GB RAM, 250 HD
which Ubuntu version works best?
Had downloaded and booted (USB, Rufus) version **18.04.1. LTS amd64**, get error message **/casper/vmlinuz.file not found**

Comment: And the winner is: 16.04.5-desktop-i386.iso. The only release that worked. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

So the best version of Ubuntu will be the latest version for 32 bit systems, in this case, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Canonical dropped support 32 bit in new releases (scr: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-drops-32-bit-desktop/ )

You can download it from here: 
http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Click on: 
ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-i386.iso          2018-07-31 01:14  1.5G  Desktop image for 32-bit PC (i386) computers  (standard download)

Comment: had tried 14.04.5-desktop-i386. didn't work either. same error message. will now try 16.04

Comment: why not a 32-bit  18.04 ubuntu derivative?

Comment: @dju did you prepared image with Rufus or something?

Comment: @Rinzwind because there is no ubuntu 18.04 for 32 bits systems? Maybe Xubuntu or another Ubuntu Budgie still have 32 bit version.

Comment: Mind the "derivative"...